# The amount of clbit arguments 0 does not match the instruction expectation (16)

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

I have a quantum circuit of 16 qubits, and I am running Amplitude Estimation on that, my final qubit to measure is 15th, so I do this

```
problem = EstimationProblem(
state_preparation = qcirc,
objective_qubits = [15],
)
```

and for Amplitude estimation:

```
# construct amplitude estimation
ae = IterativeAmplitudeEstimation(
epsilon_target=epsilon,
alpha=alpha,
sampler=Sampler(run_options={"shots": 100})
)
```

where the values of epsilon and alpha are 0.01 and 0.05

The finally when I run it:

```
result = ae.estimate(problem)
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
CircuitError: 'The amount of clbit arguments 0 does not match the instruction expectation (16).'
```

My `qcirc` has 16 qubits and 16 classical registers, I started by `qcirc` as

```
qcirc = QuantumCircuit(16,16)
```

What might be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without the code you used to define `qcirc`, but... Did you add measurements to your circuit? If you haven't, you can try running `qcirc.measure_all()` before defining your `EstimationProblem`.

Comment: Measuring the entire circuit kind of defeats the purpose, since I only want to measure one specific qubit .  qcirc is simply a 16 qubit circuit with some adders and rotation on some qubits.

Comment: Yes, that is true, you would only need to measure specific qubits (my bad), and the AE class adds registers to perform measurements for you (see line 198 and 199 [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/algorithms/amplitude_estimators/ae.py#L198)). 
Thus, I think that the problem was not lack of classical bits, but excess of them. Can you try to remove the classical bits from your circuit? i.e, do `qcirc = QuantumCircuit(16)` instead of `qcirc = QuantumCircuit(16,16)`.

Comment: Let me know if this fixes it. If this is the case, there should be a more meaningful error message in the class.

Comment: No, it did not fixed the error, but i now know why the error is there, so basically the `EstimationProblem` and the AE asks for grover operator, even tho i have specified the grover operator to be none, it's running the error from there.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no classical registers in your quantum circuit. Just make your quantum circuit

```python
qcirc = QuantumCircuit(16)
```

then do your operations and then call the `IterativeAmplitudeEstimation` function by:

```python
# construct amplitude estimation
ae = IterativeAmplitudeEstimation(
epsilon_target=epsilon,
alpha=alpha,
sampler=Sampler(run_options={"shots": 100})
)
```

If you are getting an error for Grover Operator, you can prepare a Grover operator beforehand and pass it to `EstimationProblem`

Follow this: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.29/qiskit.circuit.library.GroverOperator

Your `qcirc` is the State preparation circuit here.